# How can I select distinct inside an array based on date?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, distinct

I would like to display the value (distinctly) from my database (PostgreSQL)
here is my code:

```
SELECT distinct t.*, round(SUM(percentage)OVER (order by agentname rows between unbounded preceding and current row),3) AS cumulative
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.*,
    COUNT(*) AS frequency,
   round(COUNT(*) * 100.00 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (),4) AS percentage
  FROM 
      (select agentname,inputdate, unnest(array[ WSalamPembuka,WKonfirmasiNamaCust, WVerifikasiData,WKemampuanBertanya,WProductKnowledge,WSolusi,WAlternativeSolusi,WSistemPelaporan,WEmpati,WResponsif,WRamahSopan,WPercayaDiri,WHoldCall,WOfferHelp,WPenutup]) as weakness                        
                from call )as a 
                  WHERE a.agentname like '%wendra%' and a.weakness is not null and a.weakness !='' and a.inputdate between '01/12/2015' and  '08/01/2016'
                  group by a.agentname,a.weakness,a.inputdate
                  order by frequency desc
                ) AS t
                ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

And the result I got is:
[image]

As you can see I got duplicate data here. I want it to be like:

[image]

Any trick to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your getting duplicates is because you're grouping by the input date:

```
group by a.agentname,a.weakness,a.inputdate
```

Just remove the `inputdate` from your `group by` clause (and from the outer `select` clause), and you'll get the desired result (notice my changes by commenting out `inputdate`):

```
SELECT distinct t.*, round(SUM(percentage)OVER (order by agentname rows between unbounded preceding and current row),3) AS cumulative
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.*,
    COUNT(*) AS frequency,
   round(COUNT(*) * 100.00 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (),4) AS percentage
  FROM 
      (select agentname,inputdate, unnest(array[ WSalamPembuka,WKonfirmasiNamaCust, WVerifikasiData,WKemampuanBertanya,WProductKnowledge,WSolusi,WAlternativeSolusi,WSistemPelaporan,WEmpati,WResponsif,WRamahSopan,WPercayaDiri,WHoldCall,WOfferHelp,WPenutup]) as weakness                        
                from call )as a 
                  WHERE a.agentname like '%wendra%' and a.weakness is not null and a.weakness !='' and a.inputdate between '01/12/2015' and  '08/01/2016'
                  group by a.agentname,a.weakness/*,a.inputdate*/
                  order by frequency desc
                ) AS t
                ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

Comment: it doesn't work. .  The
a.inputdate between '01/12/2015' and  '08/01/2016' doesn't work. 
Here is the error message, 

Column a.inputdate doesn't exist.

Comment: I already found out the answer. Table a doesn't select the inputdate column, so 'where a.inputdate' will not work. so i move the 'where inputdate' inside the table a beside of 'from call' and finally It works! :D
Thankyou

Comment: @Shieryn: Yes, I'm sorry - I had commented out things a bit too eagerly. Fixed the answer to restore the `inputdate` column in the inner-most select.